# How can I use arrows option in HERE polyline?

Tags: here-api

I'm Juyeong.

I want use arrows option in polyline.
I found need setting map engine p2d for use arrows option in document.
But there didn't show how setting map engine.

I try use arrows option, but failed.

```
var style = function(feature){
    var areaLightGrade = feature.data.area_light_grade;
    feature.setStyle({
        strokeColor: '#ffffffff',
        fillColor: chooseLightGradeColor(areaLightGrade),
        lineWidth: 1
    });
};

// Create reader object initializing it with a document:
var reader = new H.data.geojson.Reader('http://127.0.0.1:8887/area_20180707.geojson', {style: style, disableLegacyMode: true});
```

Could you please tell me how can I use arrows option?

I'll looking forward your reply.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what is wrong.
I didn't set "disableLegacyMode" option.
When set that option, multipolygon did working.